# Cambiar el valor de un atributo desde la plantilla HTML a un componente en IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-framework

Tengo una app en ionic 3 que lista elementos como botones, estas se obtienen desde un provider haciendo una petición GET.

```
@Injectable()
export class CoopProvider {
  urlApi = 'http://192.168.0.42:8555/'

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

  getCoops() {
return this.http.get(this.urlApi + 'api/v1/cooperatives/')
   }
}
```

Seguido las inyecto al componente y creo una función goDetail que es la que va a llamar estos componentes mediante el HTML

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
console.log(this.coopProv.getCoops()
.subscribe(
  (data) => { // Success
    this.cooperatives = data;
  },
  (error) =>{
    console.error(error);
  })
)}

  goDetail(){
   this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage)
   }
```

Y luego las listo como botones en el template

```html
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
       <button ion-item *ngFor="let cooperative of cooperatives" (click)="goDetail()">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{cooperative.logo}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>{{cooperative.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{cooperative.short_description}}</p>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
     </ion-content>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora necesito guardar {{cooperative.name}} en una variable para poder pasarlo a la función goDetail mediante navParams y DetailPage muestre los detalles de la cooperativa seleccionada.

¿como puedo hacerlo? ¿Como cambio el valor de una variable desde la plantilla HTML al componente?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la función `goDetail()`, que se ejecuta tras clickar el botón, le puedes pasar los parámetros que tú quieras:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let cooperative of cooperatives" (click)="goDetail(cooperative)">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{cooperative.logo}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>{{cooperative.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{cooperative.short_description}}</p>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```
goDetail(cooperative: any){
  console.log(cooperative.name);
}
```

Comment: Incluso podrías pasar todo cooperative para evitar búsquedas posteriores en la lista, si fuese necesario

Comment: Editado, creo que es mejor en este caso, puede que necesite otras propiedades

Comment: Así tienes la cooperativa seleccionada dentro de goDetail() y la puedes usar como quieras, no era eso lo que preguntabas?

Comment: @DavidSilva gracias, voy a intentar como dices y te cuento

Comment: Excelente, funcionó perfecto. muchisimas gracias!!! :-D

Comment: De nada, me alegro, márcala como resuelta si lo solucionaste :)